# Is unirationality decidable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When the answer to the Lüroth problem is affirmative, the genus (for curves) or Castelnuovo's criteria (for separably unirational surfaces) give computable invariants which decide if a given variety is unirational.

I am interested in the simplest cases where non-rational examples are known: namely surfaces over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and 3-folds over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it known whether there exists an algorithm to determine if a given variety of the above type is unirational?

A naive hope would be to produce a bound on the degree of a rational map $\mathbb{P}^n \to X$ however this is clearly impossible since rational maps $\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ have unbounded degree.

The next best thing would be to put a computable upper bound on the minimal degree of such a rational map. Are such bounds known for the two cases I outlined above? Are such bounds sufficient, in principle, to provide an algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a widely studied problem, and I think with the current technology it looks unlikely this will be answered. Let me stick to characteristic $0$ for simplicity; the story gets much richer in positive characteristic (even if you add the adjective 'separably' everywhere).

Unirational varieties are rationally connected, which in turn implies $H^0(X,(\Omega_X^1)^{\otimes m}) = 0$ for all $m > 0$. Mumford conjectured that this vanishing conversely implies that $X$ is rationally connected, but I think little is known about this conjecture. At least if you believe Mumford (and maybe with a bound on which $m$ you have to try, analogous to Castelnuovo's criterion), then rational connectedness should be somewhat decidable.

However, a well-known open problem is whether every rationally connected variety is unirational (I think people expect this to be false ― I certainly do). The reason we can't answer this is that we don't have any obstructions that can distinguish between the two. Therefore, I think it's highly unlikely that we can give a characterisation that decides whether a variety is unirational.

I'm not sure what the status is on unirationality in families, but (stable) rationality is *not* a deformation invariant of smooth projective varieties by [Hassett–Pirutka–Tschinkel](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1560966694). So discrete [i.e. locally constant in families] invariants like cohomology vanishing are *not* enough to detect (stable) rationality, and very likely the same is true for unirationality.

---

As for surfaces over $\bar{\mathbf F}_p$, some K3 surfaces are unirational, but most are not, so once again it is not a deformation invariant. Shioda conjectured that if $X$ is a surface over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$ with $\pi_1^{\operatorname{\acute et}}(X) = 0$, then $X$ is unirational if and only if $H^2_{\operatorname{cris}}(X/K)$ is supersingular, i.e. all slopes of Frobenius are $1$. (This is clearly a necessary condition, since $H^2_{\operatorname{cris}}(X/K) \hookrightarrow H^2_{\operatorname{cris}}(Y/K)$ is injective and preserves Frobenius actions if $Y \twoheadrightarrow X$ is a dominant map of smooth projective varieties; see e.g. Prop. 1.2.4 in Kleiman's paper *Algebraic cycles and the Weil conjecutres* in *Dix Exposés*.)

But this doesn't say anything about what happens if $\pi_1^{\operatorname{\acute et}}(X) \neq 0$, although it has to be finite and its order indivisible by $p$ (see e.g. [this note by Chambert-Loir](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303051)). So you're first supposed to compute the universal cover and then compute slopes ― I'm not sure if there is a more direct way to do this. Assuming Shioda's conjecture this gives a criterion.

Comment: I realise that my answer is mostly about the general situation, and doesn't really address the low dimensional cases of the OP.

Comment: Thank you Remy! As you say in your answer, the general case seems pretty hopeless. For now, I will leave the question open because I'm interested in any progress made on the low-dimensional case.

Comment: There is an obstruction to unirationality proposed by Koll'ar.  The obstruction has not been computed.

Comment: @wnx  You can read more about this in Section 7 of Koll'ar's article, "Which are the simplest algebraic vareities", available here: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-04/S0273-0979-01-00917-X/S0273-0979-01-00917-X.pdf

Comment: @JasonStarr I don't see where Kollar proposes an obstruction. Could you perhaps point me to it? Thank you.

Comment: Koll'ar's "obstruction" is existence / non-existence of a rational surface containing a very general point of the variety.  The parameter spaces of rational curves on many classes of rationally connected complex manifolds are understand in some detail.  The obstruction is equivalent to proving that every uniruled subvariety of the parameter space does *not* parameterize rational curves that sweep out the manifold.  This has been proved for parameter spaces of low degree curves.